How do you pass an optional model object into a subview and know if was passed or not
I have a subview that needs a model object to work with, this view can be navigated to from a list of existing workouts or without a workout. The functionality I want is to use the passed workout if it exists or if it doesn't to immidielty Create a workout and insert it into modelContext so I can take advantage or my SwiftData relationships.
so far I have tried to use init for this:
var workout : Workout

var passedWorkout : Workout?

//If a workout was passed we assign it and if it was not we create a new one
init() {
    if let unwrappedWorkout = passedWorkout {
        workout = unwrappedWorkout
    }
    else {
        workout = Workout(id: UUID())
        print("inserting \(workout.id)")
        modelContext.insert(workout)
    }
}

but then it expects the workout to be passed so I tried changing workout to be a @State and it still says it expects it to be passed in, I also tried moving this code from init to onAppear and it produces the same error. How do I pass an optional value to a subview and then unwrap it to insert into modelContext as soon as the view is created.
As someone suggested I tried creating a workout before navigating and then passing it In but Xcode now gives me a useless buildExpression required that toolbar item button conform to view:
ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarTrailing) {       //Create a New Workout
                    NavigationLink() {
                        //Making a Temporary workout that EditWorkoutView is reponsible for adding to ModelContext
                        let workout = Workout(id: UUID(), name: "", exercises: [], startTime: Date.now, endTime: Date.now)
                                EditWorkoutView(workout: workout)
                                    .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
                        
                    } 


Please learn the basics of swift, if you have a custom type with a non-optional property without a default value then you need to pass a value for it in the init. To me it looks like you are only using one of the properties so why not keep the optional one and remove the non-optional property.

because I want to navigate to here sometimes with passing a workout and sometimes without passing a workout, this page needs to either edit an existing workout or create a brand new one

Always pas a non optional workout. Gives the responsibility to create a new workout to the caller.

ah do you mean something like this:       NavigationLink {
                    let workout = Workout(id: UUID())
                    
                    AddWorkoutView()
                        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
                    
                } label : {
                    Text("Start Workout")
                        .underline()
                    
                }


"...sometimes with passing a workout and sometimes without", and this is exactly what you use an optional parameter for.

This question is similar to: How to insert into a Model as Soon as a View is created. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Try writing this unwrapping logic inside onAppear. In the parent view use state variable to pass the passedWorkout.
var body: some View {
    Text("Workout View")
        .onAppear {
            if let unwrappedWorkout = passedWorkout {
                workout = unwrappedWorkout
            } else {
                workout = Workout(id: UUID())
                print("inserting \(workout.id)")
                modelContext.insert(workout)
            }
        }
}

Inside parent view
@State private var workout: Workout?

var body: some View {
    SubView(passedWorkout: workout)
}


I have tried it in onAppear it doesn't work

For this to work you need to make the workout property optional

It's best to make the new workout before you create the body to show it. onAppear is too late and can be called multiple times.

The only way to do this is NavigationPath
you create a navigationPath of type Workout:
  @State private var path = [Workout]()

Then in a button you can create a new workout, insert it into modelContext, then immidietly add it to the navigationPath to automatically programmatically navigate to it therefore always having a workout to work with:
Button {
                        let workout = Workout(id: UUID())
                        modelContext.insert(workout)
                        path = [workout] //push the new workout for editing right now
                        
                    }

